# Flutter Web Firebase - Get collection by sub-collection field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am building flutter web app linked with firestore. The database schema is as below:

[image: Firestore Schema]

[image: Firestore Schema]

My problem is I want to get the user document reference i.e (the company and user id) from just entering the users email address. Below is the code is my getUserRef() method:

```
Future<fs.DocumentReference> getUserRef (String userEmail) async {

String comp;
String id;
List<String> companies = await companyList();
    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
      store.collection('companies').doc(companies[i]).collection('users').get().
      then((val) {
        val.forEach((user){
          if(user.data()['Email'] == userEmail) {
            comp = user.data()['company'];
            id = user.id;
          }

        });

      });

    }
  fs.DocumentReference ref = store.collection('companies').doc(comp).collection('users').doc(id);

return ref;
 }
```

My `companyList()` method is working fine and retrieves a list of all the company doc ids. I can't figure out how to get this working and can't move on with the project without it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a collection group query, which would be a single query that searches across the `users` of all companies at once.

It'd be a query like:

```
var query = Firestore.instance.collectionGroup("users").where("Email", isEqualTo: userEmail);
var querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments();
var userDocumentRef = querySnapshot.documents[0];
```

Also see:

- [Understanding Collection Group Queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html)